# Hibernate Criteria doesn't find anything even though Query does

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to create a findZIP method for my ZipDAO implementation and the Criteria way of searching the database that I used in the same project before with success doesn't work.

This is the method I'm trying to use that doesn't work and returns null(?):

```
public ZIP findZIP(String zip){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(ZIP.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("zip", zip));
        return (ZIP) crit.uniqueResult();
}
```

But when I use this approach, it works:

```
public ZIP findZIP(String zip){
        String sql = "Select new " + ZIP.class.getName() + "(z.zip, z.city) " + " from " + ZIP.class.getName() + " z where z.zip = " + zip;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
        return (ZIP)query.uniqueResult();
}
```

The sessionFactory is an autowired bean, again, used in the same fashion in other DAOs successfully

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

I am very new to Hibernate and Spring, so it is possible that I'm doing something completely wrong, so please feel free to point things out.

And most importantly, do you have any idea why this doesn't work?

Thank you

The ZIP entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ZIP")
public class ZIP implements Serializable {

    private String zip;
    private String city;

    public ZIP(){}

    public ZIP(String zip, String city){
        this.zip = zip;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ZIP", length = 6, nullable = false)
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    @Column(name = "CITY", length = 30, nullable = false)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Edit: I am still trying to figure out why it isn't working. It actually briefly started to work at one point, but the next day it went on to throw out errors again. I will continue to investigate.